# complex integral / fractional derivative verification

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, fractional-calculus

Cauchy differentiation formula says
$$f^{(n)}(z_0)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma} \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}dz
$$

Would changing the $n$ by $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$ and factorial by $\Gamma$ make it a fractional derivative, i.e.
$$f^{(\alpha)}(z_0)=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma} \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{\alpha+1}}dz
$$

This way or another, is the following correct or how to do it correctly
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=2} \frac{\frac{1}{z-1}}{\sqrt{z-z_0}}dz
=
\frac{1}{\Gamma(-1/2+1)}\frac{d^{-1/2}}{dz^{-1/2}}\frac{1}{z-1}\Big|_{z=z_0}
=-\frac{i}{\sqrt{z_0-1}}$$

**Edit**
The question above come from trying to find, for some numerical experiment, a function $x(t)$ (that will be an exact solution of somehting) satisfying
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma x(t)t^{-k-1} dt=0, \quad k=0,1,2,3...K$$
(K some finite number) such that 
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma} \frac{x(z)}{(z-z_0)^{\beta}}dz
$$ is analytically known/obtainable (in specific branch if needed). 
Consider $\gamma$ is something regular and smooth, circle or ellipse. $\beta=1/2$ was choose for simplicity, i.e. can be anything else.

Answer (score 2):

The contour integral is not uniquely defined if $\alpha$ is fractional, because  $1/(z-z_0)^{\alpha+1}$ is multi-valued and the contour crosses a branch cut.

Comment: any chance for something more constructive? at least for the specific one I'm looking for, also see the edit...

Comment: "and the contour crosses a branch cut" - does this mean there is no way to choose a branch and therefore no way to evaluate the integral at all? hope no....

Comment: You can choose a branch, and you can evaluate the integral, but the value can depend on the choice  of branch and on the contour.